# Dart Stream with no input

Tags: stream, dart, flutter

I'm creating an app that based on firebase auth and online database with flutter and dart and bloc pattern.
I want to create a splash screen to check if user already logged in with firebase auth or not so I can direct user to another page based on current state.

So I decided to use streams for SplashScreen (that is a StatelessWidget) and create a StreamBuilder to wait for some stream return value. But in stream I don't have a input value. So should I use streams in this situation and how can I implant that.

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
Widget build(context) {
  final bloc = BlocProvider.of(context);
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: bloc.loadUser(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasData) {
        if(snapshot.data == null) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
        } else {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/main');
        }
      } else {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Loading', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Would you not provide the authenticationstate as input for the stream?
Do you plan to allow the user to log out and show the splash screen again or should the splash screen only be shown during application start until authentication is done and then not be shown until the app is closed and later restarted?

Comment: I don't think providing authenticationstate is a good way to do this. because it is a async function output. Splash screen is only for application startup just for getting data and other stuff.

Comment: Then a `FutureBuilder` should do

Comment: The problem with FutureBuilder is I can not call Navigator inside FutureBuilder

Comment: Why not? (sounds familiar, but can't remember details).

Comment: idk exactly what is the problem. but i got and error when I used Navigator

Comment: `The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<FirebaseUser>#6b0cf): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.`

Comment: I've edit the problem if you interested to see my widget code

Comment: I'm not a expert but I think this is a huge problem with flutter and bloc pattern. The problem is you should not call setState during build method and inside Navigator.push setState is called. So you can not call Navigator inside any build method and this is a problem specially when you wanted to create something like splash screen. Cause you have to check data inside build method!

Comment: Just use `Future.delayed(...)` then it will be called after build. Sorry for incomplete code, only on the phone

Comment: It's sooo insane but is's actually worked, thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

So, I implemented something similar and it goes like this :

In my main App, I check whether user is logged in in this way :

```
bool isLoggedIn = true;
@override
void initState() {
  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
    setState(() {
      isLoggedIn = user != null;
    });
  });
  super.initState();
}
```

and in my build, I change my view accordingly :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return AppProvider(
    child: MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Sample Title',
      home: isLoggedIn ? HomePage() : LoginPage(),
    ),
  );
}
```

I know this approach is not using bloc pattern entirely, but can be done that was as well. I used the bloc pattern in most areas of my project (like checking if user info is already present in my HomePage).

Comment: I think using `Future.delayed` in `FutureBuilder` is a better approach because of two reasons. First it is using bloc pattern instead of `Stateful` widget and second it makes a delay so it shows splash screen better